# Making a library with external C functions Codesys

Tags: c, codesys

Someone help me please

I have this problem when I try to use my c library in CODESYS project.
The traduction of error in English:

> The device version on the hardware seems to diverge from that used within the project. Try to synchronize the version of the device in the project with that currently on the hardware using an upgrade or downgrade"

[image]

This is what I did in this pdf:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6jKWdvnIWcKdGYxbV9TUFJQR1E

Comment: Upload your image in your question.

Comment: I did. I uploaded the image in my question

Comment: Could you describe more clearly? 
1. Have you ever connect to your devices successfully? 
2. Did you follow these steps on [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yud1lSndl9c)?  Which steps did you have problems on?

Comment: i followed these steps on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4lQGWAUTgs&t=655s and I add pdf to describe more what I do.